# Error installing cmu-sphinx with brew on OSX

Tags: homebrew

I'm getting an error when installing cmu-sphinx.

I tried adding `/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/pkgconfig` to pkg config path:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`
```

I recently doctored my brew until only these warnings are left (can't act on for a few days while away from my backup device):

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.
Update them from Software Update in the App Store.

Warning: You have leftover files from an older version of Xcode.
You should delete them using:
  /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder

Warning: Your Xcode (6.0.1) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 6.2.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store.
```

I've also done a recent `brew upgrade`.

Here is the trace:

```
JMAIR-3:~ juliusskye$ brew install cmu-pocketsphinx -v
==> Installing dependencies for cmu-pocketsphinx: libsamplerate, cmu-sphinxbase
==> Installing cmu-pocketsphinx dependency: libsamplerate
==> Downloading http://www.mega-nerd.com/SRC/libsamplerate-0.1.8.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libsamplerate-0.1.8.tar.gz
==> Verifying libsamplerate-0.1.8.tar.gz checksum
tar xf /Library/Caches/Homebrew/libsamplerate-0.1.8.tar.gz
==> Patching
patching file examples/audio_out.c
==> ./configure --disable-dependency-tracking --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.4.0
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... Cfg/install-sh -c -d
checking for gawk... no
checking for mawk... no
checking for nawk... no
checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for gcc... clang
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether clang accepts -g... yes
checking for clang option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for style of include used by make... GNU
checking dependency style of clang... none
checking whether clang and cc understand -c and -o together... yes
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether clang++ accepts -g... yes
checking dependency style of clang++... none
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed
checking how to print strings... printf
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3/sed
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for fgrep... /usr/bin/grep -F
checking for ld used by clang... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... /usr/bin/nm
checking the name lister (/usr/bin/nm) interface... BSD nm
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 196608
checking whether the shell understands some XSI constructs... yes
checking whether the shell understands "+="... yes
checking how to convert i386-apple-darwin13.4.0 file names to i386-apple-darwin13.4.0 format... func_convert_file_noop
checking how to convert i386-apple-darwin13.4.0 file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
checking for /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
checking for objdump... no
checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
checking for dlltool... no
checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
checking for ar... ar
checking for archiver @FILE support... no
checking for strip... strip
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm output from clang object... ok
checking for sysroot... no
checking for mt... no
checking if : is a manifest tool... no
checking for dsymutil... dsymutil
checking for nmedit... nmedit
checking for lipo... lipo
checking for otool... otool
checking for otool64... no
checking for -single_module linker flag... yes
checking for -exported_symbols_list linker flag... yes
checking for -force_load linker flag... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... clang -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for dlfcn.h... yes
checking for objdir... .libs
checking if clang supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... yes
checking for clang option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if clang PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if clang static flag -static works... no
checking if clang supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if clang supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the clang linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin13.4.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
checking whether to build static libraries... yes
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... clang++ -E
checking for ld used by clang++... /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld
checking if the linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... no
checking whether the clang++ linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking for clang++ option to produce PIC... -fno-common -DPIC
checking if clang++ PIC flag -fno-common -DPIC works... yes
checking if clang++ static flag -static works... no
checking if clang++ supports -c -o file.o... yes
checking if clang++ supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
checking whether the clang++ linker (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld) supports shared libraries... yes
checking dynamic linker characteristics... darwin13.4.0 dyld
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for windres... no
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for ANSI C header files... (cached) yes
checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
checking sys/times.h usability... yes
checking sys/times.h presence... yes
checking for sys/times.h... yes
checking size of int... 4
checking size of long... 8
checking size of float... 4
checking size of double... 8
checking processor byte ordering... little
checking for malloc... yes
checking for calloc... yes
checking for free... yes
checking for memcpy... yes
checking for memmove... yes
checking for alarm... yes
checking for signal... yes
checking for floor in -lm... yes
checking for floor... yes
checking for ceil... yes
checking for fmod... yes
checking for SIGALRM... yes
checking for lrint... yes
checking for lrintf... yes
checking processor clipping capabilities... none
checking for pkg-config... /usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for SNDFILE... yes
checking for FFTW3... no
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating Makefile
config.status: creating M4/Makefile
config.status: creating src/Version_script
config.status: creating Win32/Makefile
config.status: creating Win32/Makefile.mingw
config.status: creating src/Makefile
config.status: creating examples/Makefile
config.status: creating tests/Makefile
config.status: creating doc/Makefile
config.status: creating libsamplerate.spec
config.status: creating samplerate.pc
config.status: creating src/config.h
config.status: executing depfiles commands
config.status: executing libtool commands

-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-= Configuration Complete =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-

  Configuration summary :

    Version : ..................... 0.1.8

    Host CPU : .................... i386
    Host Vendor : ................. apple
    Host OS : ..................... darwin13.4.0

-e   Tools :

    Compiler is GCC : ............. yes
    GCC major version : ........... 4

  Extra tools required for testing and examples :

    Use FFTW : .................... no
    Have libsndfile : ............. yes

  Installation directories :

    Library directory : ........... /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib
    Program directory : ........... /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/bin
    Pkgconfig directory : ......... /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/pkgconfig

Compiling some other packages against libsamplerate may require 
-e the addition of "/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/pkgconfig" to the 
-e PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable.

==> make install
Making install in M4
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-data-am'.
Making install in src
  CC     src_sinc.lo
  CC     samplerate.lo
  CC     src_zoh.lo
/bin/sh ../libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=compile clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes  -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -pipe -c -o src_zoh.lo src_zoh.c
/bin/sh ../libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=compile clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes  -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -pipe -c -o src_sinc.lo src_sinc.c
  CC     src_linear.lo
/bin/sh ../libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=compile clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes  -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -pipe -c -o samplerate.lo samplerate.c
/bin/sh ../libtool --silent --tag=CC   --mode=compile clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.     -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes  -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -pipe -c -o src_linear.lo src_linear.c
  CCLD   libsamplerate.la
test -z "/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib" || ../Cfg/install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib"
test -z "/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/include" || ../Cfg/install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/include"
 /bin/sh ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libsamplerate.la '/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 samplerate.h '/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/include'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsamplerate.0.dylib /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/libsamplerate.0.dylib
libtool: install: (cd /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib && { ln -s -f libsamplerate.0.dylib libsamplerate.dylib || { rm -f libsamplerate.dylib && ln -s libsamplerate.0.dylib libsamplerate.dylib; }; })
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsamplerate.lai /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/libsamplerate.la
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libsamplerate.a /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/libsamplerate.a
libtool: install: chmod 644 /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/libsamplerate.a
libtool: install: ranlib /usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/lib/libsamplerate.a
Making install in doc
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `install-exec-am'.
test -z "/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/share/doc/libsamplerate0-dev/html" || ../Cfg/install-sh -c -d "/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/share/doc/libsamplerate0-dev/html"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 SRC.png SRC.css index.html license.html history.html download.html lists.html quality.html win32.html faq.html api.html api_simple.html api_callback.html api_full.html api_misc.html '/usr/local/Cellar/libsamplerate/0.1.8/share/doc/libsamplerate0-dev/html'
Making install in examples
  CC     sndfile-resample.o
clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../src -I./../src -fpascal-strings -I/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon   -I/usr/local/Cellar/libsndfile/1.0.25/include  -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes  -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -pipe -c sndfile-resample.c
  CC     varispeed-play.o
  CC     audio_out.o
clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../src -I./../src -fpascal-strings -I/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon   -I/usr/local/Cellar/libsndfile/1.0.25/include  -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes  -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -pipe -c varispeed-play.c
  CC     timewarp-file.o
clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../src -I./../src -fpascal-strings -I/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon   -I/usr/local/Cellar/libsndfile/1.0.25/include  -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes  -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -pipe -c timewarp-file.c
clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../src -I./../src -fpascal-strings -I/Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon   -I/usr/local/Cellar/libsndfile/1.0.25/include  -g -O2 -std=gnu99 -W -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes  -Waggregate-return -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wnested-externs -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -pipe -c audio_out.c
  CCLD   timewarp-file
  CCLD   sndfile-resample
In file included from audio_out.c:171:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:23:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:20:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:31:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Finder.h:240:3: error: unknown type name 'Point'
  Point               location;               /* File's location in the folder */
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Finder.h:246:3: error: unknown type name 'Rect'
  Rect                windowBounds;           /* The position and dimension of the folder's window */
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Finder.h:248:3: error: unknown type name 'Point'
  Point               location;               /* Folder's location in the parent folder */
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Finder.h:261:3: error: unknown type name 'Point'
  Point               scrollPosition;         /* Scroll position (for icon views) */
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Finder.h:284:3: error: unknown type name 'Point'
  Point               fdLocation;             /* File's location in folder. */
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Finder.h:312:3: error: unknown type name 'Rect'
  Rect                frRect;                 /* Folder's window bounds */
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Finder.h:314:3: error: unknown type name 'Point'
  Point               frLocation;             /* Folder's location in parent folder */
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/Finder.h:327:3: error: unknown type name 'Point'
  Point               frScroll;               /* Scroll position */
  ^
In file included from audio_out.c:171:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Headers/Carbon.h:20:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Headers/CoreServices.h:23:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/AE.framework/Headers/AE.h:20:
In file included from /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/CarbonCore.h:35:
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:123:8: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
extern Fixed 
       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:137:8: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
extern Fixed 
       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:139:3: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
  Fixed   a,
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:140:3: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
  Fixed   b)                                                  __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
  ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:152:10: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
FixRound(Fixed x)                                             __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:163:8: error: unknown type name 'Fract'
extern Fract 
       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:164:10: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
Fix2Frac(Fixed x)                                             __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:176:10: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
Fix2Long(Fixed x)                                             __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
         ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:187:8: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
extern Fixed 
       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:199:8: error: unknown type name 'Fixed'
extern Fixed 
       ^
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/CarbonCore.framework/Headers/FixMath.h:200:10: error: unknown type name 'Fract'
Frac2Fix(Fract x)                                             __OSX_AVAILABLE_BUT_DEPRECATED(__MAC_10_0, __MAC_10_8, __IPHONE_NA, __IPHONE_NA);
         ^
fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=]
20 errors generated.
make[1]: *** [audio_out.o] Error 1
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
==> Formula
Path: /usr/local/Library/Formula/libsamplerate.rb
==> Configuration
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew.git
HEAD: d9e67a7d2263a3db71ce33b819ea87739588c628
Last commit: 13 hours ago
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.9.5-x86_64
Xcode: 6.0.1
CLT: 6.0.0.0.1.1410400753
Clang: 6.0 build 600
X11: 2.7.7 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 2.0.0-p481
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /usr/local/bin/python => /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /Users/juliusskye/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
Java: 1.8.0_45
==> ENV
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_PATH: /usr/local/opt/flac/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libogg/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libvorbis/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/opt/libsndfile/lib/pkgconfig
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.9
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/flac/bin:/usr/local/opt/libsndfile/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

Error: libsamplerate 0.1.8 did not build
Logs:
     /Users/juliusskye/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libsamplerate/01.configure
     /Users/juliusskye/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libsamplerate/01.configure.cc
     /Users/juliusskye/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libsamplerate/02.make
     /Users/juliusskye/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libsamplerate/02.make.cc
     /Users/juliusskye/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libsamplerate/config.log
```

Comment: i might try this version:
https://github.com/watsonbox/homebrew-cmu-sphinx

Comment: same errors building libsamplerate

Comment: it seems to be having a problem finding these mactypes: `#include <MacTypes.h>`

Comment: Looks like you need to follow the instructions given "Warning: Your Xcode (6.0.1) is outdated
Please update to Xcode 6.2.
Xcode can be updated from the App Store."

Comment: i tried from the app store. it tried to install 6.32 and lists under incompatible updates. i guess ill have to install 6.2 manually since 6.3 is only for osx >=10.10 apprently and i have 10.95

Comment: You only need the command line tools that are available directly https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2339/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014588-CH1-DOWNLOADING_COMMAND_LINE_TOOLS_IS_NOT_AVAILABLE_IN_XCODE_FOR_OS_X_10_9__HOW_CAN_I_INSTALL_THEM_ON_MY_MACHINE_

Comment: ok i will try updating devtools cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reinstalling developer tools and installing XCode v 4.2 (highest possible for oSX 10.95) it still didnt fix the issue. The issue was fixed by removing the /Developer folder which had previous xcode stuff in it.

`sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-developer-folder .`
`sudo rm -rf /Developer`

Comment: well done sir! Note: I did _not_ remove the entire Developer folder. I re-ran the newest Xcode which prompted me to install some components. The compilation worked flawlessly.